# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, jsp

Hey guys i have this error message, i connect between server and client , select data from mysql server and insert it in mysql client but the insert statement not happen

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''context'.login VALUES (1,'Alamal','alamal','alamal','alamal)' at line 1

and this is the code..

```
<%
try{
Connection con1;
Connection con2;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con1=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.101.1:3306/context","hospital","0000");
PreparedStatement ps1=(PreparedStatement)con1.prepareStatement("SELECT * from hospital");
String str;
ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();

while(rs1.next()){
con2=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/context","root","");
con2.setAutoCommit(true);
con2.createStatement();
    int id=rs1.getInt("ID");
    String username=rs1.getString("UserName");
String password=rs1.getString("Password");
String hname=rs1.getString("HospitalName");
    String haddress=rs1.getString("HospitalAddress");
    PreparedStatement state= (PreparedStatement)con2.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 'context'.'login' VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);");
    state.setInt(1, id);
    state.setString(2, username);
    state.setString(3, password);
    state.setString(4, hname);
    state.setString(5, haddress);
    state.executeUpdate();
    con2.close();      
    }
   con1.close();

} catch(Exception ex){
    out.print(ex);
}
%>
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the single quotes from `'context'.'login'`?

Comment: this message appear com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4MYSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'context.login' doesn't exist

Comment: Then make shure it does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have silly mistake in writing SQL query now it will work fine.

```
<%
try{
Connection con1;
Connection con2;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con1=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.101.1:3306/context","hospital","0000");
PreparedStatement ps1=(PreparedStatement)con1.prepareStatement("SELECT * from hospital");
String str;
ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();

while(rs1.next()){
con2=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/context","root","");
con2.setAutoCommit(true);
con2.createStatement();
    int id=rs1.getInt("ID");
    String username=rs1.getString("UserName");
String password=rs1.getString("Password");
String hname=rs1.getString("HospitalName");
    String haddress=rs1.getString("HospitalAddress");
    PreparedStatement state= (PreparedStatement)con2.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `context`.`login` VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);");
    state.setInt(1, id);
    state.setString(2, username);
    state.setString(3, password);
    state.setString(4, hname);
    state.setString(5, haddress);
    state.executeUpdate();
    con2.close();      
    }
   con1.close();

} catch(Exception ex){
    out.print(ex);
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes (`'`) in SQL are used to denote string literals, not object names. Just drop them and you should be fine:

```
INSERT INTO context.login VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
```